# WebGL: this extension has very low support on mobile devices

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, webassembly, qopenglwidget

I wrote a simple example that draws a quad with a texture. When I run this example as WebAssembly: https://profound-sunflower-a5633b.netlify.app/ I see this message in the browser console: `WebGL: this extension has very low support on mobile devices; do not rely on it for rendering effects: WEBGL_polygon_mode`

It happens in the JS file on the `GLctx.getExtension(ext);` line:

```js
        // .getSupportedExtensions() can return null if context is lost, so coerce to empty array.
        var exts = GLctx.getSupportedExtensions() || [];
        exts.forEach(function(ext) {
          // WEBGL_lose_context, WEBGL_debug_renderer_info and WEBGL_debug_shaders are not enabled by default.
          if (!ext.includes('lose_context') && !ext.includes('debug')) {
            // Call .getExtension() to enable that extension permanently.
            GLctx.getExtension(ext);
          }
        });
```

How to hide this message?

My example: [simple-texture-in-one-file-opengl-qt6-cpp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lglx8nsoi3bw7lrjt7z0o/simple-texture-in-one-file-opengl-qt6-cpp.zip?rlkey=qymccjwbpe2x6od467us54og6&dl=1)

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QtOpenGLWidgets/QOpenGLWidget>

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, private QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    OpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
        , m_texture(QOpenGLTexture::Target::Target2D)
    {
        setWindowTitle("OpenGL, Qt6, C++");
        setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        setFixedSize(350, 350);
    }

private:
    void initializeGL() override
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        // qDebug() << "OpenGL version:" << (const char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
        // qDebug() << "GLSL version: " << (const char*) glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << "\n";
        // qDebug() << "Vendor: " << (const char*) glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << "";

        m_texture.create();
        m_texture.bind();
        m_texture.setData(QImage(":/assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png").mirrored());
        m_texture.setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear);
        m_texture.setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::WrapMode::ClampToEdge);

        // Create and compile shaders
        shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Vertex,
            "attribute vec2 vertexPosition;"
            "attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;"
            "varying vec2 texCoord;"
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);"
            "    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;"
            "}");

        shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Fragment,
            "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
            "precision mediump float;\n"
            "#endif\n"
            "varying vec2 texCoord;"
            "uniform sampler2D textureSampler;"
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texCoord);"
            "}");

        // Create vertex buffer
        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        vertexBuffer.create();
        vertexBuffer.bind();
        vertexBuffer.allocate(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    }

    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    void paintGL() override
    {
        // Clear the buffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use shader program
        shaderProgram.bind();

        // Bind texture
        m_texture.bind();

        // Bind vertex bufffer
        vertexBuffer.bind();
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexPosition");
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexTexCoord");
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexPosition", GL_FLOAT,
            0, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexTexCoord", GL_FLOAT,
            sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);

        // Draw quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    }

private:
    QOpenGLBuffer vertexBuffer;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    QOpenGLTexture m_texture;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    OpenGLWidget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

simple-texture-in-one-file-opengl-qt6-cpp.pro

```
QT       += core gui openglwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS +=

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    assets.qrc
```

assets.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png

[image: box_texture_512x512.png]

Comment: This issue is also present in [completely different toolkits like Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140504), so it looks like the browser itself is giving that warning.

Comment: I don't understand who can add ability to hide this message: Qt developers or emsdk developers. I created the issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122040

Comment: Cross ref: https://forum.qt.io/topic/154368/webgl-this-extension-has-very-low-support-on-mobile-devices

Comment: They should add the ability to hide this message and print a name of the extension that "has very low support on mobile devices". I added the info about printing a name of the extension in the bug report.

Comment: As I said, this is a browser/Chrome issue. Especially you were able to trigger it from Javascript code, which is neither Qt nor Emsdk

Comment: But the js-file is created automatically with Qt (or emsdk). This message happens at 6872 line of code. Do you mean I should open the js-file and edit it every time when I deploy my apps? I what the ability to hide the message or disable WebGL extensions because I don't use them.

Comment: What is the simplest solution to hide this message? Maybe every time before deploying an app to the hosting a user must: 1) open the automatically generated js-file 2) go to 6872 line of code 3) delete the line: `GLctx.getExtension(ext);`

Comment: Disabling extensions willy-nilly is an excellent way to fuck up your application.

Comment: But who enabled the extensions that I don't need? Who generated that code that enables all extensions?

Comment: I program in pure WebGL 1.0 too and I don't use any WebGL-extension

Comment: The piece of code you showed literally asks for all supported extensions and enables them. If you are really allergic to this warning message, switch to Firefox which does not print it. Whoever generates it, it would not be appropriate to disable extensions based on the status in 2024. For all we know this extension is widespread in 2025 and then you'll have legacy applications printing that false warning forever.

Comment: As a developer I should to know how to hide this message when customer will require it.  That piece of code was automatically generated by Qt or emsdk. That js-file contains 13471 lines of code. I think it is not normal that I should open this file and edit it manually to fix the problem every time when I what to deploy an application.

Comment: Shrug. If you want to waste your own time trying to hide a warning message that was [added to Chrome barely three months ago](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/40900b5e6698955aba32af9679519104c3bad20f) and might disappear in another three months, have fun. I would go do something more productive with my time

Comment: I understand now. Yes, you are right. I closed the Qt bug report. Thank you very much!

Comment: @8Observer8 Just making sure you are aware of Chromium's site: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/ and searching for existing issues: https://issues.chromium.org/issues and the possibly related ones: https://issues.chromium.org/issues?q=webgl_polygon_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Chrome issue. Read **Botje's** comments.